# How to tell if an error was suppressed by the @ error control operator?

Tags: php, error-handling, suppress-warnings, error-suppression

A 3rd party library I'm using uses the @ error suppression operator in its codes which causes suppressed errors via @ still cause an error output because I am using a custom error handler `(set_error_handler())`.

In this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) it says

> If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

However it is unclear how exactly can I catch the errors that was preceded by an @.

My question is how can I catch errors that was suppressed via @?

Comment: As it says: your error handler will still be invoked as usual, but calling `error_reporting()` inside your error handler will yield `0`. So your error handler should take that into account and act accordingly. Not sure what's unclear here…?

Comment: @deceze Ahhh, I misread it. Also, I didn't know `error_reporting()` actually returns something valuable. Thanks! You can post that as answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says: your error handler will still be invoked as usual, but calling `error_reporting()` inside your error handler will yield `0` if the error was produced in the context of an `@`. So your error handler should take that into account and act accordingly.