# Proper way to handle errors suppressed by @?

Tags: php, error-handling, suppress-warnings, error-suppression

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), calling `error_reporting()` will return `0` if the error came from an `@` suppression. But since my production server is always set to `error_reporting(0)` (on top of the script), calling `error_reporting()` would always return to `0`.

How can I actually catch or differentiate a legitimate error vs an error suppressed by `@`?

Right now my error handler is something like this:

```
if (error_reporting() == (E_ALL OR -1))
    echo 'display specific error';
elseif (error_reporting() == 0)
    echo 'display general error';
```

Note: This is related to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550522/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mu.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#%22Unasking%22_the_question) You should not set `error_reporting` to `0`, even in production.

In development, you'll want to set the error reporting level to the highest possible to be notified about any and all errors or notices or deprecation messages or possible issues that may pose problems in the future.

In production, you'll want to set the error reporting level to only include errors and perhaps warnings, but not things like deprecation notices. This is to keep your *error logs* from superfluous information and be able to effectively track down production errors.

Because you should always **log errors**.

What you should not do in production is *display errors* on screen. That's what `ini_set('display_errors', true|false)` controls. You still want *error reporting* on production, just that that goes into a log file.

Comment: Yes my errors are always logged but I want to inform the user that an error occurred. So I guess the proper way to put in the error handler after logging is: `if (error_reporting() == 0) { // do nothing } else { echo 'general error message'; }` Is that recommended?

Comment: It is not the job of your error handler to do any user interaction. The error reporting level is a global value that specifies what kind of errors ***you*** (the developer) are interested in hearing about. It filters errors into "not interested" and "interested in". The error handler and/or ini configuration from there either output these errors on screen and/or write them to a log. This is all about *technical* errors a user should never ever see. Displaying something to the user is a business logic decision and not handled at this level.

Comment: Those kinds of errors are done at the level of `if (!someFunction()) { echo "Please try again."; }`. `someFunction` here may or may not produce an errors/notice/warning which your error handler writes to a log and/or displays on screen. But that is entirely separate from what the user is supposed to see.

Comment: I understand what about errors that are from 3rd party libs or DB connection failure that a user can't do anything about unless it's fixed by the dev? Where do we put the general error that say's something is wrong, can't proceed yet?

Comment: Something like a DB connection failure should raise an exception or `exit` the script with an error code, e.g. `exit 1`. That should cause the web server to trigger its `500` response code behaviour and output its error page. Alternatively, you handle that more manually like `if (!$db = connect()) { echo 'Error!'; exit 1; }`. – The error handler is truly only about detailed error information relevant to the developer, never about user-facing error handling.

Comment: If you have a 3rd party library which produces developer-facing errors which *should* cause the termination of the app, but on its API side it somehow pretends  all is great (i.e. it doesn't even `return false` or such), then… you're somewhat screwed. The best you can do is weird workarounds through an error handler, but I'd need to see a really concrete case there first before endorsing that.

Comment: Ok. Reason I asked this question is because a 3rd party lib used `@exif_read_data` and my error handler shows a generic "error occurred" message to the user. Internally, it's just a E_WARNING notice as shown in the logs. You reckon, I shouldn't show any message at all to the user on this case?

Comment: Exactly. That `@` exists for a reason then, perhaps that library has a fallback plan in case an error occurred and doesn't want to bother you with those details. All that matters in the end is whether the library returns the expected result or not. Base errors you show to users on that.

Comment: Got it. I think I'm getting it now. So basically putting `if (error_reporting() == 0) { // do nothing } else { echo 'general error message'; }` in the error handler is generally okay as this will only show a generic error message to the user for "real" or more serious errors that aren't suppressed by `@`?

Comment: Again, you should not conflate `error_reporting()` with any message the user is supposed to see at all. `error_reporting` and error handlers are only *developer tools.* User UI is *business logic*.

Comment: Ok sorry if I seem to be just repeating myself. Well say I want the script to halt for E_WARNING or E_NOTICE and simply tell the user "Something is wrong, go back later". Isn't that supposed to be handled by the error handler? If not where should I set that?

Comment: If you really want to do that… okay. But again, that seems to me to be the wrong place. As in the case with the library which seems *to expect* certain errors to happen and suppresses them (and then hopefully does something useful), you can't separate one from the other. Errors just happen under the cover, and your error handler just decides where those errors should go. It shouldn't make assumptions about the grander business logic and whether the entire request should be aborted or not.